# Fullcalendar - Problem with JSON DATA from External File

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar

I would like to pull some events from the database. But first of all, one would be enough. I don´t know whats wrong cause i dont get any error messages...

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        locale: 'de',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: 'example.org/termine/PartnerTermine/&id=Xsdfeecvsdfgerger}'
        });
```

});

If i am goin to call my events url, the answer is:

```
{"title":"Termin 1","start":"1575675560"}
```

And also, when i´m going to array it to

```
[{"title":"Termin 1","start":"1575675560"}]
```

the Event wont be showed, i dont know why.

The other php-file:

```
$meine_termine = array(  // OR $meine_termine[] = array( - both doesnt work.
    "title" => 'Termin 1',
    "start" => '1575675560'
    );

$json_termine =  json_encode($meine_termine);

echo $json_termine;
exit;
```

The question is:
What is wrong and why doenst it pull the event from my file...

thanks a lot in advance.

Andre

Comment: You can't `echo` a JSON object or array in php. You can use [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to display the object data.

Comment: Why you have a curly bracket in this url (or your real API URL) "example.org/termine/PartnerTermine/&id=Xsdfeecvsdfgerger}" i think you should remove it or try to open it directly in the browser and see if it's really returning something. If it's returning something measns something if wrong with your JS , check console and network tab to find out if the API is being called.

Comment: Thanks für your replies. Firstly, thanks...the Echo of cause.. second: has to be removed here, but in real there is a smarty var in { }

Answer (score 1):

Question closed, found a solution.

JS-Side:

```
eventSources: [

// your event source
{
  url: 'https://example.org/termine/PartnerTermine/&id=hash_id',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    custom_param1: 'something',
    custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
  }
}
```

]

php-side:

```
foreach ($termine AS $termin)
{
    $meine_termine[] = array(
    "allDay"    => "",
    "title"     => $termin['title'],
    "id"        => $termin['title'],
    "end"       => "",
    "start"     => $termin['datum']
    );

}

$json_termine =  json_encode($meine_termine);

echo ($json_termine);
exit;
```

The Fields for the calendar has to be id, title, allday,end,start. works fine if the json will be echo'ed.